# How to add variable in Localizable swift

Tags: swift, localizable.strings

I search a solution for my problem. If I have a string in localizable.string for example:

```
"stringExample" = "My name is ";
```

How can I add properly the name ?
I don't want do `string = string + "userName"`

Any solution?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html for all the formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"stringExample = "My name is %@";` and use the localized string as a string format:

```
let fmt = NSLocalizedString("stringExample", "")
let myNameIs = String(format: fmt, "Max")
```